# Property must be initialized or be abstract when creating empty variable without assigning it a value directly kotlin

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

I am doing something fairly simple in a Scratch-File in IntelliJ.

```
val number1 = 12.5
val number2 = 3.5
var result: Double

result = number1 + number2
println(result)
```

This gives me no output, but this

> Property must be initialized or be abstract

Why is that?

Comment: @Agent_L I am very new to Kotlin/Java, so I do not know about hint one. I would assume that it is a placeholder for a value of type double. Reading your hint two, I guess its not being a placeholder in the way I expect it is. What I do not understand: There are various examples doing it this way... https://programiz.com/kotlin-programming/operators or https://play.kotlinlang.org/byExample/01_introduction/03_Variables and I would assume it works?!

Comment: NVM. It works for me in a project, and works in scratch file if wrapped in a function. Dunno why it doesn't work in bare code - starts working when initialized. Seems like a bug or omission in the scratch file executor. Disregard what I've said before, the variables can be unitialized if you're not accessing them. I barely use `var`s in Kotlin, it's all `val something = expression`, Kotlin makes it easy to avoid mutability

Comment: This is a bug. I created an issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-23679/Scratch-Property-must-be-initialized-or-be-abstract-with-uninitialized-variable